# Bootstrap CSS location and github pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

I'm trying to upload a webpage to github pages using jekyll and want to make sure all my pages and posts 'see' the bootstrap 3 stylesheets, which in my working directory is simply in a css folder in the root directory: ./css/

If I use the following in my home page:

```
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Then the homepage (index.html in root) loads and is formatted correctly, however if I have pages located in other places or folders, they wont see this because ./ is relative to the current directory - as far as my understanding goes. I tried to get around this issue with Jekyll:

```
<link href="{{site.url}}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{site.url}}/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.url}}/css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Which results in:

```
<link href="ward9250.github.io/HybRIDS/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="ward9250.github.io/HybRIDS/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ward9250.github.io/HybRIDS/css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

However if this is in the homepage it does not load correctly formatted with any of the settings or styles of bootstrap or my custom modifications and overrides.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this so all my pages, no matter where they are can see my stylesheets.

Thanks,
Ben.

EDIT

I've just found something strange - if I set my HTML to:

```
<link href="/HybRIDS/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/HybRIDS/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/HybRIDS/css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Then the page loads correctly. However I thought we were to avoid absolute paths like /?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have solved the issue, but to future readers: Yes, the solution is to include direct path due to github project pages' url structure. The following excerpt is taken out from [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/).

> Project Page URL Structure
>
> Sometimes it’s nice to preview your Jekyll site before you push your
>   gh-pages branch to GitHub. However, the subdirectory-like URL
>   structure GitHub uses for Project Pages complicates the proper
>   resolution of URLs. Here is an approach to utilizing the GitHub
>   Project Page URL structure (username.github.io/project-name/) whilst
>   maintaining the ability to preview your Jekyll site locally.
>
> 1. In _config.yml, set the baseurl option to /project-name – note the leading slash and the absence of a trailing slash.
> 2. When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: {{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/css.css – note the slash immediately following the variable
>      (just before “path”).
> 3. When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: {{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }} – note that there is no slash between
>      the two variables.
> 4. Finally, if you’d like to preview your site before committing/deploying using jekyll serve, be sure to pass an empty
>      string to the --baseurl option, so that you can view everything at
>      localhost:4000 normally (without /project-name at the beginning):
>      jekyll serve --baseurl ''