# GitHub Pages build cannot find bootstrap sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages site (a **project** page) that uses Jekyll and would like to use Bootstrap in my project.
I downloaded the uncompiled twbs files and added the bootstrap, mixins and utilities folders under a `_sass` directory in my project.

I import bootstrap in my main sass file like so:

```
@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap';
```

This works fine locally when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

However when I push the build to GitHub Pages I get the following error:

```
Your SCSS file ci-dashboard/assets/css/style.scss has an error on line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/bootstrap. Load path: /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.4/_sass.
```

I have tried the following:

1. Adding this to my _config.yml file

```
sass:
    sass_dir: _sass
    style: compressed
```

2. Following the instuctions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968754/bootstrap-css-location-and-github-pages) by adding a baseurl to my config.yml file and attempting to import bootstrap in my main css file with the following line:

```
@import '{{ site.baseurl }}/bootstrap/bootstrap';
```

This solution seemed very promising as it seems there's an issue with jekyll and GitHub pages using relative links? I'm guessing I have that import wrong or in the wrong place?

3. Replacing `vendor` in my .gitignore file with `vendor/bundle` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869979/jekyll-site-fails-only-when-pushed-to-github).

Here is the structure of my project:

```
├── _config.yml
├── _sass
│   ├── bootsrap
│   |   └──*lots of .scss files*
│   ├── mixins
│   |   └──*lots of .scss files*
│   └── utilities
│       └──*lots of .scss files*
├── assets
│   └── css
│       └──style.scss
├── _includes
│   ├── footer.html
│   └── header.html
├── _layouts
│   └── default.html
├── _site
└── Gemfile
etc. etc.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also posted here https://github.community/t/github-pages-build-cannot-find-bootstrap-sass/139376

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found your answer but I had the same issue. Local test worked fine and github deployment failed with exactly the same error message.
I thought something was missing in my config file or my gemfile but all was fine.
In fact, it was just my repository structure which was wrong.

When I cloned my github-pages repository, I created the new jekyll project inside the repository, that was my mistake. Github doesn't expect an intermediate folder.

My structure was like this :

```
username.github.io
|_ jekyll-project-name
  |_ _layouts
  |_ _includes
  |_ _sass
  |_ index.html
```

The structure should be like this to be built by github :

```
username.github.io
|_ _layouts
|_ _includes
|_ _sass
|_ index.html
```

Maybe it's the same problem for you.

And just in case, check if you have this in your gemfile :

```
# gem "jekyll"
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

You don't need site.baseurl on your bootstrap import.